# Ember.js: How to stay in Leaf Route on model change, when link-to goes to parent resource

Tags: ember.js

I have a list of posts, with a nested summary and full route.:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('post', {path: ':post_id'}, function() {
    this.route('summary', {path: '/'});
    this.route('full');
  });
});
```

The summary route is at `path: /`, so when I `{{#link-to 'post' somePost}}`, it arrives in `post.summary`.

When I change the model, i.e. route to `someOtherPost`, I would like to stay in the current leaf route (either summary or full).

How do I do this? I tried `willTransition`, but I'm not sure how to check if the model changed:

Here's a JSBin with what I have so far: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/benot/2/edit?js,output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a great use case for a dynamic link-to.

### link-to Code

```
App.ApplicationController = Em.ArrayController.extend({
  postLink: 'post'
});
```

### Template

```
{{#each item in controller}}
  <li>{{#link-to postLink item}}{{item.title}}{{/link-to}}</li>
{{/each}}
```

You can send an action from each child route, and it will go up the router (http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/actions/) until caught.  At the parent route you can change the dynamic value of the link-to and bam, you're good to go.

### Route Code

```
App.PostSummaryRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  actions:{
    didTransition: function(){
      this.send('swapLink', 'post.summary');
    }
  }
});

App.PostFullRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  actions:{
    didTransition: function(){
      this.send('swapLink', 'post.full');
    }
  }
});


App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return [
      App.Post.create({id: '1', title: 'Foo', body: 'Lorem'}),
      App.Post.create({id: '2', title: 'Bar', body: 'Ipsum'})
    ];
  },
  actions: {
    swapLink: function(newLink){
      console.log('swapLink ' + newLink);
      this.controller.set('postLink', newLink);
    }
  }
});
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/dekokafu/1/edit

Comment: Do I need to enable a feature or something for this? I seem to be missing something. The link doesn't render for me and instead adds a loading class to each `tr` inside the `{{#each}}` block. Really bizarre.

Comment: What?  hitting run with js doesn't work?  I just opened it again and it started up just fine, maybe try just hitting the output page http://emberjs.jsbin.com/dekokafu/1

Comment: It's working in the JSBin, but in my project it's not working. Sorry it's probably unrelated to your example, but unfortunately I can't share my project code. Attempting to debug it right now.

Comment: Awesome, worked. The problem was that I had `{{#each controller}}` instead of `{{#each item in controller}}` so the context inside the loop changed and my dynamic `postLink` was undefined. This left my `{{link-to}}` in an "inactive loading state". There was a warning in console, but I didn't see it for the longest time.